# How to set a variable to a string?

Tags: php, string

There is any possibility making something like that using PHP?

```
<?php

$number = 1;

$str_$number = "BlahBlah";

// and make this: $str_1 = "BlahBlah";

echo $str_1;

?>
```

Comment: any reason you're not using arrays?

Comment: because he do not want an array, he want dynamic variable names. this part seems clear?

Comment: Yes, dynamic variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$number = 1;
${'str_'.$number} = 'foobar';
echo $str_1;//foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
$number = 1;
${'str_' . $number} = 'foobar';
?>
```

Comment: Dont seems to work, if I try to echo $str_1, i get a blank page :(

Comment: of course it won't. even though the braces do exist in variable names, they must start from the dollar sign to not parse error. like `${$number}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$number = 1;
$value = 'str_' . $number;
$$value = 'blahblah';
echo $str_1;
?>
```

Comment: good job Felix. Although might be worth noting that the $$ makes that variables value a variable. Which is what he wanted just how it was accomplished is note worthy in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
$number = 1;
eval('$str_'.$number.' = "foobar";');
echo $str_1;
```

Comment: Yes it is risky, I just said this is another way; because in this specific case it not getting something from php variables like _GET, _POST and etc, that's why he can also try this.